# Stop Chrome from turning my relative links to absolute links when using 'Save File As...'

Tags: html, google-chrome, cgi

Quite simply: I am outputting an html file from a cgi program that uses internal anchors relative to the same document.  I wish users to be able to save this file from my url an use that file locally.  Which is exactly what you would expect and get from a relative URL, and works in Firefox and IE.

However Chrome is 'filling out' all the relative links in the saved document with the absolute URL from my website location without being asked to.

How can I suppress this behaviour?

Comment: Got any solution ?

Comment: no mate i gave up i guess it's a relatively minor inconvenience when all is said and done, for me at any rate.

Comment: Well, the reason browsers do is because **relative links decrease SEO of the webpage**. But anyway, there should be an option to disable it :-/

Comment: @ʀᴀʜɪʟ i don't really see how the manner in which a browser views a website will affect SEO, or the manner in which it saves the links in a local file export will affect it either but OK.  I know nothing about SEO sothat is useful to know.

Comment: If your webpage contains relative links, it will not be indexed fully by search engines. that's why browsers convert them to absolute but they should at least provide a choice.

Comment: @RAHIL TBH mate that doesn't make sense at all, how MY browser treats a webpage has absolutely zero effect on what Google is going to do with it....

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use javascript to parse all links upon loading the page and remove the "absoluteness" of the link and just retain the relative portion.

Comment: that's a hell of a lot of work to correct something a browser ought not to be doing in the first place... also the links are not the same every time, there is no way to differentiate between the links I want absolute and the links I want to remain relative in the original output.  Lastly that would require a JS overhead in every document that is entirely unnecessary for FF and IE and all other browsers... I'm looking for a way to to tell Chrome to Stop It.  Thanks though it was worth a shot.

Comment: Yea I ran into the same issue and just gave up.  Lucky for me we already have local working copies of the file so I just instructed team to copy from file manager instead of right clicking and 'save as...'

Comment: You could just tell them to use Firefox... ;-)